# How to over-ride a php file from parent theme

Tags: php, wordpress, overriding

I know this question might sound generic, but the answers to those generic questions is not working for me.

I am very new to touching wordpress php files, and I am working for a client using the FitPro theme (I will be posting on their general forum but my client no longer has support :/). I need to change the permalink for the cutom post type defined as "fitness-class" and replace it with "classes".

I found where the slug is defined (it is in a file called custom_post_types.php and it is located at 'framework/presentation/custom_post_types.php'). I confirmed that changing the file of the parent theme achieves the desired affect, however it does not work when I try to replicate it in the child theme.

I copied the custom_post_types.php file to my root directory in the child theme, made the change and it did not work. I replicated the file path of the parent theme and it still did not work. I looked up the problem online and, among others, came across this solution : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/child-theme-fix-use-get_template_part-instead-include-get_template_directory.

My Problem (at least right now): My theme does not appear to have a front-page.php file. Instead there is a file at 'framework/framework.php' that includes the following line: require_once(MO_FRAMEWORK_DIR . '/presentation/custom-post-types.php');

How do I go about over-riding this specifically? There is no get_template_directory call  for me to over-ride as far as I can tell as the above solution stated.

I tried commenting out the line and then copying the framework.php file to both my child theme root directory and I tried copying the parent theme file path. I tried adding the get_template_part call to both my functions.php file and the framework.php file. I do apologize if I am clueless here, but I have not yet gotten to the point of learning the wordpress structure.

Any advice is greatly appreciated thank you. I have no idea where MO_FRAMEWORK_DIR is defined, but if I do find it and it solves my problem I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever file you have to override from the parent theme then you have to copy this file and you have to put simply in the child theme

For Example if u have to override single.php file of the parent theme. Then you can simply copy the single.php file and put it to child theme.

Create folder in you child theme as below.

framework/presentation/

And under the presentation folder put the custom_post_types.php

I hope you understand.

Comment: I did this, it did not work. The link I provided in my original comment is to a wordpress forum explaining why, however my theme is not configured in the way that link would suggest.